# Was Richard told something along the lines of loose lips in Stone of Tears?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

So I just started Blood of the Fold. Richard told the cook that Kahlan is alive, then the cook was interrogated by Tobias with his lie detector sister.

Wasn't Richard told in Stone of Tears something along the lines of don't babble; guard your tongue; basically that he should be circumspect.

Comment: If you're looking for logical consistency in this series, you are going to be more and more disappointed as you go on.

Answer (score 0):

It is much more complicated than that simple rule.

It was common knowledge that Kahlan Amnell was alive. She was alive, as Richard's bride to be, as Queen of Galea. Zedd's death spell worked as follows: everyone was convinced that Mother Confessor was executed, and they forgot who she was, her name and origin, her identity. They remembered only the general appearance (as per prophecy: The One In White). Zedd was sure that such deception would serve the purpose of satisfying the prophecy and letting Kahlan get away from the immediate danger.

Now with Tobias Brogan and his sister. They were suspecting some sort of a ruse from the very start, and were determined to find the truth by finding *'strands of the web'* from all possible sources.

> <sup>**Blood Of The Fold, Chapter 11**</sup>
>
> Tobias realized his sister was right. “You know about magic. Tell me how we can know her.”
>
> Lunetta shook her head. “Lord General, I do not know how to see the **strands of a wizard’s web** that was cast for the express purpose of hiding. I tell you only what would make sense, and that be that if such a spell were used to hide her, then we, too, would not recognize her.”

One cook alone would not be enough to prevent them from gaining it.

> They were both gifted, although Tobias did not know that

thus as soon as one of them detected the true identity of Kahlan and said that aloud - the spell would fail.

> <sup>Blood Of The Fold, Chapter 17</sup>
>
> Lunetta leaned close, peering at him. “But Lord General, I told you, the wizard’s web hides her identity from us. We cannot see the strands of a web like that. We will not know her.”
>
> A grin tightened the scar at the side of Tobias Brogan’s mouth.
>
> “Oh, but I have seen the strands of the web. The Mother Confessor’s name be Kahlan Amnell.”

Now, to the Stone Of Tears. The Wizard's Second Rule defined there was simple:

> <sup>Stone Of Tears, chapter 63</sup>
>
> The Second Rule is that the greatest harm can result from the best intentions

Apart from that , there are no specific words of warning.

Comment: I could have sworn that someone gave advice to Rand to be circumspect in Stone of Tears. Oh well, I could be wrong. I'm on the fourth book now, and am starting to have doubts about the series overall.